# Facebook login FB.ui, access token is empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-ui

I'm trying to authenticate users in my facebook app. I'm using the following code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fbIsReady);
        FB.init({ appId: app_id, channelUrl: channelUrl, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 0);
      };

      (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
      } (document));


function fbIsReady(res){
  fbReady = 1;
  var params = {method: "oauth", "scope": 'publish_stream'};
  FB.ui(params, isLoggedIn);
}

function isLoggedIn(res){
  if(!res || res.status === 'not_authorized' || res.perms != 'publish_stream')
    fbIsReady();
  else if(res.hasOwnProperty('selected_profiles')){
    FB.api('/me', {access_token: FB.getAccessToken()}, checkUserInfo);
  }
}

function checkUserInfo(){
    console.log(res); // return the error bellow right after the user gives permissions and the expected result after refresh
}
```

My problem is that after the user authenticates in the app the Access token is not set. I need to refresh the page for it to work. I would think that after the user auths I would be able to perform FB.api('/me'...) but I get:

> code: 2500 message: "An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user." type: "OAuthException"

Until I refresh the page. Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: You did not show us, where you call these methods, and what the parameter `res` is supposed to represent.

Comment: I did. fbIsReady is a callback function. It is defined on the window.fbAsyncInit and when called it contains the response from facebook. The same applies to isLoggedIn function

Comment: And what is `callback` in `isLoggedIn` supposed to be? Btw., normally there should be no need to set the access token yourself – the SDK automatically takes care of that for you in most cases.

Comment: yup. sorry. updated the question

Comment: `FB.getAccessToken` is not an officially documented method of the JS SDK. Please try using just `FB.api('/me', checkUserInfo)`, without trying to pass the access token yourself.

Comment: Only works after refresh also. Thanks